# how to make checked all child node for selected node in ultrawintree in infragistics?

Tags: infragistics, treenode, ultratree

I have ultrawintree control in my application. Now i want to make checked all the child node of selected treenode in tree.

I am new in windows application. So please help to find out the solution for the same.

So can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: WinForm Controls which Veroisn Infragistics?

Comment: @AkshayJoy  i am using 12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are adding the check boxes to the nodes by setting the [NodeStyle](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinTree.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.Override~NodeStyle.html) to Checkbox you could handle the AfterCheck event and update the children in this event:

```
void ultraTree1_AfterCheck(object sender, NodeEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UltraTreeNode node in e.TreeNode.Nodes)
        node.CheckedState = e.TreeNode.CheckedState;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Property **SelctionType** as **Extended** to Allow Multiple Selection.

```
Me.UltraTree1.Override.SelectionType =
    Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.SelectType.Extended
```

Create Method Iterate the Each node under Checked Nodes, and `Selected = true`

node Varible is the node which you Checkecd , you will get the Node form EventArgs

```
  foreach(UltraTreeNode child in node.Nodes)

    node.Selected = true;
```

Comment: Selection isn't related to the checked state of the nodes if they are created by setting the NodeStyle to Checkbox.